# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay from class method not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Any idea why this isn't working?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(foo:) withObject:argObj afterDelay:5.0];
```

I am calling this from within a class method, and it is calling another class method for the same class (hence 'self').  Is this valid?

I placed a breakpoint in foo, but it is not called.  What's going on here?

Comment: Should be working. Can you post the method definition of foo: and the method you are? Are you on the main thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a run loop running on the thread from which you invoke the `perform:afterDelay:`? If not, it won't run.

Comment: This was the problem.  I had never even heard of that requirement.  Thank you.

Comment: If your code is surrounded by an autorelease pool that will kill it.

Comment: can you please elaborate how to carry out the thing? feeling like dumb :(

Comment: Sure -- ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but why are you using the `self` keyword in a static context in the first place? Why not simply change `self` to the name of the class?

Comment: Because the context isn't static. `self` may be the class, or it may be any subclass of the class (or any subclass of those, etc). Just like how `self` in an instance method isn't always an instance of the class - sometimes it's an instance of the subclass or another descendent.

Comment: Ah, very good to know. I had previously assumed that 'self' in Objective-C was similar to 'this' in Java, which cannot be used in a static context. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In Obj-C, classes themselves are objects. Class methods are, quite literally, just instance methods on the metaclass (the metaclass is basically the class's class). Class methods are called the exact same way instance methods are, the only difference is the method is looked up on the metaclass instead of the class. This means `self` works in class methods exactly the same way as in instance methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

[The method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003706) is an instance method, the receiver should be an instance of class. It needs a concrete object to perform the action. So I don't think it will work in class method.

Comment: performSelector does work with a class + class method (confirmed in 10.6). So your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Classes are just instances of the meta class.  It should work fine.